# HTML/CSS -- How to add a selected state

Tags: javascript, html, css

At the top of my webpage I have all of my links laid out horizontally as such:

Link 1         Link 2        Link 3     etc...

What I'm trying to do is, when you click on Link 1 for example, a border-bottom:1px solid #000 gets added to the css. If I were to click link 2, then the border-bottom on link one would be set to 'none' and the border-bottom:1px solid #000 would be set on link two.

I guess what I'm trying to ask is, how do I add an onclick handler to all of the links in my menu bar? So that, a "selected" class would be added to the link for the current page, and when I click another link, that class is removed and added onto the next link.

I've tried using javascript but I'm unable to remove the selected class after I've added it. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: jQuery has an easy `toggleClass` function: https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/. Have you used jQuery before?

Comment: Are the contents of the page updated in place via javascrt or is a new page loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a class="menu" href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu" href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu" href="#">3</a></li>
  </ul>
```

then

```
$('a.menu').click(function(){
    $('a.menu').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

then in your css something with that active class

```
.active{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery:
Add this into onclick inside that

```
$("#id").addClass("classname");

<style>
#id { 
height: 20px;
width: 20px;
}
.classname { 
 display: none; 
}
</style>
<a href="#" onclick="$("#id").addClass("classname");">Link 1</a>
<div id="id"></div>
```